# How can I add background color to a libGDX TextButton?

Tags: libgdx

I have a `TextButton` in my libGDX project and I want to add a color background to it. I tried the `setColor()` method but that didn't work.

Comment: What specific symptoms of not working did you observe? Did the wrong thing change colour? Did nothing change colour? Did something change to the wrong colour? Showing your code in context might help spot potential causes of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Can you edit your question to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you tried?